# Highcharts arearange draggableHigh and draggableLow not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, highcharts, react-highcharts

According to the documentation, [series.arearange.dragDrop](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.arearange.dragDrop) should accept `draggableHigh` and `draggableLow` (both defaulting to `true`) to allow the high and low points of the range to be dragged individually. In other words, not only moving the range up or down, but also making it narrower or wider. But I can't get it to work. Code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
// Import Highcharts
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import more from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import draggable from "highcharts/modules/draggable-points";

import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

if (typeof Highcharts === "object") {
  more(Highcharts);
  draggable(Highcharts);
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HighchartsReact
          highcharts={Highcharts}
          constructorType={"chart"}
          options={{
            credits: {
              enabled: false
            },
            title: {
              text: ""
            },
            tooltip: {
              valueDecimals: 2,
              shared: true
            },
            legend: {
              enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
              type: "datetime"
            },
            yAxis: {
              title: {
                text: ""
              },
              min: 0
            },
            series: [
              // …
              {
                name: "Range",
                data: [[0, 8, 3], [1, 1, 1], [2, 6, 8]],
                type: "arearange",
                dragDrop: {
                  draggableY: true,
                  draggableHigh: true,
                  draggableLow: true
                },
                lineWidth: 0,
                linkedTo: ":previous",
                color: "lightBlue",
                fillOpacity: 0.3,
                zIndex: 0,
                marker: {
                  enabled: false
                }
              }
            ]
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-u151p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect data structure:

```
data: [
  [0, 8, 3],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [2, 6, 8]
]
```

is mapped to `'x', 'low', 'high'` and `low` can not be greater than `high`.

You need to change the data order or use `keys` property.

Also, you need to enable the marker. Remove the following:

```js
marker: {
  enabled: false
}
```

---

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.arearange.data

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.arearange.keys

Comment: Thanks. I tried fixing the data in https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-mn2um, but the problem persists. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Yngve Høiseth, You need to additionally enable the marker: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-std0o